# Multiple button presses AsyncTasks freezing UI

Tags: java, android

I have a button that performs an `AsyncTask` HTTP Get request. However, multiple rapid presses of this button often freeze the button UI in the pressed state (it uses an `XML selector`) and I'm not sure why. I thought AsyncTasks didn't affect the UI. Can someone please provide insight as to why the button freezes up sometimes?

I've tried `execute` and `executeOnExecutor` with no difference.

The `onClickListener`:

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (buttonEvent > 0) {
            String url = "bogusurl" + buttonEvent.toString();
            System.out.println(url);
            try {
                HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
                //request.execute(url).get();
                request.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (jumpPage > 0) {
            loadPage(jumpPage);
        }
    }
});
```

And the AsyncTask Class itself:

```
public class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String stringUrl = params[0];
        URL myUrl;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            myUrl = new URL(stringUrl);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            Log.d("Request", "Sending command");
            connection.connect();
            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is freezing cause your calling get() which returns a result and will wait for the response if it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),

> `get()` method will wait if it is necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Remove `get()` method. Because of it, your main thread is waiting for the response from the background task.

If you want to process the result of your AsyncTask class, then it is better you override `onPostExecute(Result result)`. It runs after `doInBackground(Params... params)` with the result.

Comment: Ah thank you! I totally missed that I was using .get().